# Python JSON indexing

Tags: python, json, zabbix

I get a response from get method in Zabbix like that here:
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference/host/get

The JSON output looks like if I print the whole response:

```
{
    "property1": "value1",
    "property2": "value2",
    "property3": "value3"
}
```

The problem is, that I cannot index it correctly. I tried `response["property1"]` gave me this error:

> 'ZabbixApiObject' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Also I did try convert JSON like that:

```
json.load(response)
```

> The error it gave me:  'NoneType' object is not callable

What can be the problem? Is there any way to split this response? I need one attribute from that.

**EDIT**:

```
  request_command = {
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "method": "hostgroup.get",
            "params": {
                "output": "extend",
                "search": {
                    "name": "testgroup"
                }
            }

        }
        test_request = json.loads(requests.post("http://localhost/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php", json.dumps(request_command)).text)
```

Comment: From the first error message, it seems like you're using a high-level API for Zabbix rather than manually fetching the API pages. The API is parsing the JSON for you. Refer to its documentation.

Comment: You should check in the documentation if `ZabbixApiObject` has a `text()` method or something similiar that returns the response as a string. Then you can use `json.loads(reponse_as_string)`

Comment: I edited my post, but it's not working yet. 
I get this error: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Are you using this: https://github.com/baniuyao/ZabbixPythonApi as a wrapper? The json you are using for your edit is valid and should be able to be accessed by index. perhaps you need to make the call with ```host = zapi.createObject(Host, 'HostToCreate')```

Comment: I am using basic: zabbix_api. I don't get your HostToCreate part of your comment.